# How do I enforce stronger password requirements on my Craft site?

Tags: users, password

Craft’s only password requirements are that it is between 6 and 160 characters long. I want to require my users to enter passwords that are at least 7 characters long, with at least one number and one capital letter.

Is it possible to enforce these stricter requirements, or do we have to wait for [this feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/10459731-better-stricter-rules-for-password-input-upon-regi) to be accepted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In Craft 2**

Plugins have the power to enforce stricter password requirements using the [users.onBeforeSetPassword](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onBeforeSetPassword) event.

Add this code to your plugin’s [primary class](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/setting-things-up#your-primary-plugin-class):

```php
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('users.beforeSetPassword', array($this, 'onBeforeSetPassword'));
}

public function onBeforeSetPassword(Event $e)
{
    $user = $e->params['user'];
    $password = $e->params['password'];

    // Perform our custom validation logic here
    $validates = true;

    if (mb_strlen($password) < 7)
    {
        $validates = false;
    }
    else if (!preg_match('/(\d.*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*\d)/', $password))
    {
        $validates = false;
    }

    if (!$validates)
    {
        // Set $performAction = false so the password doesn't get saved
        $e->performAction = false;

        // Add a custom validation error on the user
        $user->addError('newPassword', 'Sorry but your password must contain an uppercase letter, a number, a haiku, a gang sign, hieroglyph, and the blood of a virgin.');
    }
}
```

**In Craft 3**

Craft 3 doesn't have a `beforeSetPassword` event, but you can pull the same thing off from your plugin's init() method using the User element's `User::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE` event like so:

```php
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Event::on(
        User::class,
        User::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE,
        function (ModelEvent $event) {
            // Check if a new password was set on the user
            if ($event->sender->newPassword) {
                $password = $event->sender->newPassword;
                $errors = [];

                // Perform our custom validation logic here
                $validates = true;

                if (mb_strlen($password) < 7) {
                    $validates = false;
                    $errors[] = 'Too Short!';
                }
                else if (!preg_match('/(\d.*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*\d)/', $password)) {
                    $validates = false;
                    $errors[] = 'Too Simple!';
                }

                $event->isValid = $validates;

                if (!$validates) {
                    /** @var User $user */
                    $user = $event->sender;
                    foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        $user->addError('newPassword', $error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I've adapted Brandon Kelly's answer into a plugin, [craft-password-enforcer](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/craft-password-enforcer).

Comment: @BrandonKelly is there a way to stop the default craft error displaying if the password is less then 6 characters? As it is confusing for the user to show one error stating it needs to be 6 then another error again if I set my default length to be higher than this (10 for example).

Comment: @TerryUpton Good question. Right now I don't think that’s possible, unfortunately.