# Error message regarding password in user registration form

Tags: form, error-message

I have a custom registration form in my Craft site based on this info.
https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/user-registration-form.html

And I want to show error message when the password doesn't meet the requirement.

First of all, I made a password requirement like here, and defined a few error messages.
[How do I enforce stronger password requirements on my Craft site?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12165/how-do-i-enforce-stronger-password-requirements-on-my-craft-site)

However, no error message appears even if the password is not fine.
Just the form redirects to the same form page, without any message.

So, could you tell me how to set the error message?

Please not that it works fine in the login form to dashboard, like here;
{SiteURL}/admin/

- My Craft version is 2.7

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us the plugin code you're using as well as the template code?

Comment: Do you mean the code for password restriction? Then, it is almost the same as my second link.